# what's the meaning of the “gty” claim in a jwt token?

Tags: oauth, jwt

I have decoded JWT token using 'jwt.io' . I found one claim 'gty' in payload section. What is the meaning and significance of it.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation explicitely saying that, but it sems to be the `grant_type` You'll find values as `password`or `client_credentials`

Comment: Who issued this JWT? What other claims are used?

Comment: It is issued by 'auth0.com'. There are several other claims like - 'iss', 'iat', 'exp'  etc.

Comment: Could you give us the value of the claim? Maybe it helps a bit.

Comment: The value for the claim is 'client-credentials'

Answer (score 25):

`gty` is not a registered claim name as defined in [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4).

Although I could not find any reference clearly stating it, it seems
[auth0.com](https://auth0.com) uses `gty` for the [`grant_type`](https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-grant-types) that was used to request the token. e.g. [`client-credentials`](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/client-credentials) or [`password`](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant)

[Here's an example](https://community.auth0.com/t/password-grant-requesting-specific-scopes-causes-response-to-have-no-scopes/11845/6) in the Auth0 community in which `grant_type password` and the `gty` claim are mentioned.

Comment: +1 for me, especially thanks for your notice of the Auth0-specific grant_type. This is only returned with a clientid/secret combination and not, for example, with implicit grant where a user authenticates with username and password in a frontend application.

Comment: can confirm this is correct.I use it in a .Net filter to determine if the caller is system (ie client-credentials) or not, before then checking if they have the expected scope. In our case, the endpoint needs to be accessible to both system and user.